# Uno Platform WASM results on a blank page

Tags: .net-core, uno-platform

I'm studding Uno Platform and I have installed the UnoTemplates 2.4 version:

```
dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet::2.4
```

And created a new solution using:

```
dotnet new unoapp-prism –o UnoApp
```

The Shared project comes with a ContentControl named Shell:

[image]

But I added a Page named MainPage and updated the code on App.CreateShell():

[image]

```
    sealed partial class App
    {
        ...

        protected override UIElement CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainPage>();
        }

        ...
    }
```

When I try to run the Wasm project I just have a blank page on my browser.

Uno guides says that I need **.Net Core 2.2**, but I have the 3.1 on my PC that came when I installed VS2019. Could this be the problem? I don't want to uninstall the 3.1 version. Is there a way to install the 2.2 version and select which version to use?

Comment: .NET Core uses side-by-side execution, you can install .NET Core 2.2 without affecting 3.1 version

Answer (score 1):

It was rendering well. The problem was because I didn't set the Grid's Background. The TextBlock was white and I couldn't see it.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

It's necessary to set the Background to all elements inside a Page. I added a Pivot inside a Page and I couldn't see even its Titles. When I set its Background, I figured out the problem.

```
<Pivot Title="Super Barato"
       Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
```

[image]

Thanks and I hope I helped others.